# How can I control the access of an API at definition/operation level in WSO2 API store console?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Ex: Lets assume I have a 'Calculator' API and it has below operations/definitions.
1.addition
2.multiplication

I want restrict user with addition operation and remaining operations should not be visible/access in store console.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the access for each resource by configuring scopes for each resources. If the user has access token binding to the particular scopes only can invoke the resources restricted with the scopes. Documentation has detailed useful information regarding this - https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/01/article-an-overview-of-scope-management-with-wso2-api-manager/

Comment: Can we hide Api operations(which are not having access to user) based on user login to wso2 store console?

Comment: Store console is directly using swagger-ui, hence I don't think it is possible to hide resources. But we can restrict who invokes the resources